Asymptote sphere is "blotchy" and conversion from PDF to SVG is fuzzy and marred by lines
I am just starting to use Asymptote to generate a ball diagram of nitric oxide.
My MWE is a file called ball.asy:
settings.tex = "lualatex";
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;

import three;

pen Maroon = RGB(128, 0, 0);
pen Teal = RGB(0, 128, 128);
unitsize(5cm);

/* Code below inspired by the examples at
http://dominique.vrel.free.fr/latex2.htm
*/

draw(shift(0.3, 0.6, 0.9) * scale3(0.21) * unitsphere, Maroon, light = Viewport);
draw(shift(0.3, 0.3, 0.3) * scale3(0.2) * unitsphere, Teal, light = Viewport);

currentprojection = perspective(2, 3, 4);

The output PDF image from asy ball.asy has "blotches" in the bottom as shown. 
Q1. How may I remove the "blotches"?
I actually need an SVG for web graphics and tried to convert the PDF to svg using pdftocairo -svg ball.pdf ball-cairo.svg  but that image has horizontal stripes and looks blurry. I tried online PDF to SVG converters but their SVG "spheres" were not even spherical.
Q2. How do I get usable SVG output from the PDF put out by asymptote.

Useful SVG output may be a problem, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201148/asymptote-svg-export-as-vectors-instead-of-rendered-how. That is from 10 years ago but I think the situation has not changed much.
